# AngularJs sort object in ngRepeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm using AngularJs and found a problem in ordering properties of a hash object in a template.
My object is like:

```
function TestCtrl($scope){
    $scope.week = {'MONDAY': ['manuel'], 'TUESDAY': [], 'WEDNESDAY': ['valerio'], 'THURSDAY': ['manuel', 'valerio'], 'FRIDAY': []}
}
```

Now, when I try to print these values in my template:

```
<div ng-repeat="(day, names) in week">
    <span>{{day}}</span>
    <ul> <li ng-repeat="name in names">{{name}}</li> </ul>
</div>
```

The order of the days printed is different: `FRIDAY MONDAY THURSDAY TUESDAY WEDNESDAY`

I tried to apply the filter `orderBy` but I think it doesn't work with objects, but just with arrays...

How can I order it?

Comment: I dont think its related to angularjs. The object keys get sorted alphabetically by default.

Comment: @CodeHater, it is related to AngularJS and no, object keys won't be sorted in any way in javascript engines. The only thing described in the official spec is that the order can not be guaranteed, but however, it is a de-facto standard that all browsers keep the order of string object keys and don't sort it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As per AngularJS [docs](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.20/docs/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) (version 1.3.20):

> You need to be aware that the JavaScript specification does not define
>   what order it will return the keys for an object. In order to have a
>   guaranteed deterministic order for the keys, Angular versions up to
>   and including 1.3 **sort the keys alphabetically**.

A workaround is to use an array of keys:

```
function TestCtrl($scope){
    $scope.week = {
        'MONDAY': ['manuel'], 'TUESDAY': [], 
        'WEDNESDAY': ['valerio'], 'THURSDAY': ['manuel', 'valerio'],    
        'FRIDAY': []}

    $scope.weekDays = ["MONDAY", "TUESDAY", "WEDNESDAY", "THURSDAY", "FRIDAY"];
}
```

Use the array in view for iteration:

```
<div ng-repeat="day in weekDays">
    <span>{{day}}</span>
    <ul> <li ng-repeat="name in week[day]">{{name}}</li> </ul>
</div>
```

---

Update from AngularJS version 1.4.6 [docs](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.6/docs/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat):

> Version 1.4 removed the alphabetic sorting. We now rely on the order
>   returned by the browser when running `for key in myObj`.

Comment: "JS Object keys get sorted alphabetically by default ": This is not true. AngularJS does the sort: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngRepeat.js#L345

Comment: True to that, @MArc, there's also a lot of debate trying to remove this 'feature': https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6210

Comment: Starting with 1.4, the keys are not sorted alphabetically anymore. This is documented as a breaking change here: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes-6

Answer (score 6):

There is no way to order hash objects like that. Not just in angular but in javascript in general.

I would convert the hash object to an array of objects, something like that:

```
$scope.week = [{day: 'MONDAY', names: ['manuel']}, {day: 'TUESDAY', names: []} ...];
```

And then change the view to something like that:

```
<div ng-repeat="day in week|orderBy:'day'">
    <span>{{day.day}}</span>
    <ul> <li ng-repeat="name in day.names">{{name}}</li> </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Again, not true "There is no way to order hash objects (...) in javascript in general.": Object.keys({day: 'MONDAY', names: ['manuel']}, {day: 'TUESDAY', names: []}) -> returns ["day", "names"]

Comment: What you're suggesting is a workaround (a legit one) to order objects via another array. There is no way to order the objects themselves.

Comment: did you downvote me? Anyway I did not suggest to actually sort objects. IMO the object should be presented `as is` without sorting it. I'd like to remove this line of code from Angular's source code: `collectionKeys.sort();` (my code was just a demonstration)

Comment: There is a way how to order an object ... look at my answer ;)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18124665/angularjs-sort-object-in-ngrepeat/35452200#35452200

Answer (score 3):

This was fixed in Angular 1.4.  As stated in the official Angular documentation below:

> Version 1.4 removed the alphabetic sorting. We now rely on the order
>   returned by the browser when running `for key in myObj`

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Answer (score 3):

There is actually a simple solution ...
The object keys are not ordered by default **BUT** if you create the object in browser from scratch your browser **WILL** know the order ;)

Example:

```
// test-1
var data = {};
data['a'] = 10;
data['b'] = 5;
data['c'] = 2;

Object.keys(data); // ["a", "b", "c"]


// test-2
var data = {};
data['b'] = 5;
data['a'] = 10;
data['c'] = 2;

Object.keys(data); // ["b", "a", "c"]
```

So simply ... recreate the object ... or use this simple filter:

```
.filter('orderObject', function () {
    return function (object, reverse) {
        var keys = Object.keys(object || {}).sort();
        if (reverse) keys.reverse();
        for (var ordered = {}, i = 0; keys[i]; i++) {
            ordered[keys[i]] = object[keys[i]];
        }
        return ordered;
    }
})
```

Example with regular objects:

```
<!-- MARKUP : DEFAULT -->
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in data">
        <td>{{key}}</td>
        <td>{{value}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<!-- RESULT : test-1 -->
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<!-- RESULT : test-2 -->
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Example with sorted objects:

```
<!-- MARKUP : with FILTER orderObject:<reverse?> -->
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in data | orderObject">
        <td>{{key}}</td>
        <td>{{value}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<!-- RESULT : test-1 without reverse -->
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<!-- RESULT : test-2 with reverse -->
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>10</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

This question is old, but I ended up coming up with an answer to this that I thought might be an improvement on some of the previous answers.

Rather than simply convert the object into an array, it's much more DRY to create an angular filter that does that for you, and then `ngRepeat` or `ngOptions` over that.

As an example:

```js
angular.module('myproject')
    .filter('objOrder', function () {
        return function(object) {
            var array = [];
            angular.forEach(object, function (value, key) {
                array.push({key: key, value: value});
            });
            return array;
        };
    });
```

Then, with an object like:

```
    $scope.degrees: {
        ASC: "Associate's",
        BAS: "Bachelor's",
        MAS: "Master's",
        MD: "M.D.",
        JD: "J.D.",
        PHD: "Ph.D",
        OTH: "Other"
    }
```

We could use it like so:

```html
<select
    ng-model="myDegree"
    required
    ng-options="item.key as item.value for item in degrees | objOrder"
    >
</select>
```

This way, you neither have to create a new array and pollute `$scope`, nor do you have to go back and change your actual `degrees` object, which could have unwanted side-effects.

Comment: This is not a workable solution, because the filter always return a new instance of array, the dirty checking will go into infinitive loop.

Comment: @FredYang I have used this method in production without issue