# angularjs ng-repeat alphabetical order

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

Is there any way to avoid the alphabetical order of the ng-repeat directive? I mean, I request a Dictionary from an MVC Web Api formatted into Json. Looks this way:

```
{
"FormaTablero":{"Id":"FormaTablero","Descripcion":"Forma tablero","Tipo":1,"Tipo_visualizacion":2,"Visible":true,"Valor":"Cuadrado","Disabled":false,"Obligatorio":true,"Dominio":["Cuadrado","Redondo","Rectangular"]},
"AnchoTablero":{"Id":"AnchoTablero","Descripcion":"Ancho tablero","Tipo":1,"Tipo_visualizacion":1,"Visible":true,"Valor":"170","Disabled":false,"Obligatorio":true,"Dominio":null},
"LargoTablero":{"Id":"LargoTablero","Descripcion":"Largo tablero","Tipo":1,"Tipo_visualizacion":1,"Visible":false,"Valor":"","Disabled":false,"Obligatorio":false,"Dominio":null},
"DiametroTablero":{"Id":"DiametroTablero","Descripcion":"Diametro tablero","Tipo":1,"Tipo_visualizacion":1,"Visible":false,"Valor":"","Disabled":false,"Obligatorio":false,"Dominio":null},
"CantidadPatas":{"Id":"CantidadPatas","Descripcion":"Cantidad patas","Tipo":1,"Tipo_visualizacion":2,"Visible":true,"Valor":"4","Disabled":true,"Obligatorio":true,"Dominio":["4"]},
"LargoPatas":{"Id":"LargoPatas","Descripcion":"Largo patas","Tipo":1,"Tipo_visualizacion":1,"Visible":true,"Valor":"120","Disabled":false,"Obligatorio":true,"Dominio":null},
"Ruedas":{"Id":"Ruedas","Descripcion":"Ruedas","Tipo":1,"Tipo_visualizacion":2,"Visible":false,"Valor":"","Disabled":false,"Obligatorio":false,"Dominio":["Sí","No"]},
"Frenos":{"Id":"Frenos","Descripcion":"Frenos","Tipo":1,"Tipo_visualizacion":2,"Visible":false,"Valor":"","Disabled":false,"Obligatorio":false,"Dominio":["Sí","No"]}
}
```

After requesting the complex object(Dictionary) I visualize it in html in this way:

```
<div class="control-group" ng-repeat="valor in controlET.varTE" ng-show="valor.Visible">
    <label class="control-label">{{valor.Descripcion}}</label>
    <input ng-show="valor.Tipo_visualizacion == 1" type="text" class="input" ng-disabled="valor.Disabled" ng-model="valor.Valor" ng-enter="controlET.funciones.onChangeTE()">
    </input>
    <select ng-show="valor.Tipo_visualizacion == 2"  name="v" ng-model="valor.Valor" ng-disabled="valor.Disabled" ng-options="v for v in valor.Dominio" ng-change="controlET.funciones.onChangeTE()">
    </select>
</div>
```

This code piece visualized the data this way:

[image]

So it is shown in alphabetical order, which doesn't make sense with the goal of the app. Any ideas of how to solve it?

Thank in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18124665/angularjs-sort-object-in-ngrepeat

Comment: Well the thing is that I don't know how's gonna be the dictionary I request. I can't make the help array manually, and I can't do it dinamycally cause the object arrives to the client side sorted.

Comment: I think this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19287716/skip-ng-repeat-json-ordering-in-angular-js